# What does XHit mean in the combat system of Final Fantasy II?

Tags: final-fantasy-2

I'm playing Final Fantasy II on the iPhone. During the combat phase, my characters often display a 'X'Hit, where 'X' is a number like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. When I went to Altair to have the combat system explained to me, there was no explanation. What do these numbers mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Final Fantasy 2(j) has an unusual (for a Final Fantasy game) way of dealing with how your party does damage.

Most Final Fantasy games give your characters a very high percentage chance to hit.  Not so in FF2 - in FF2, you take a number of swings at the enemy, and some of those connect and some do not.  This is modified by a few things, chiefly:

- Your character's weapon proficiency, which is raised by using a particular weapon class.  Each level (100 points) of this proficiency grants an additional hit, to a max of 16.  Note that you don't actually have to complete the action in order to gain a point - you can select the action and then cancel it before you end your turn and get credit for a point.  (At least in most versions - I've played the Mobile Java, GBA, and PSX versions and they all worked this way)
- The weapon and your character's Hit% stats.  Most of the early game weapons have severe (-20% easily) Hit%, which lowers your character's chance to hit an enemy.

When you see this "XHit" the game is letting you know how many of your characters hits connected, after all the various modifiers are taken into account.  Your damage will range accordingly.

Comment: Awesome. Is there a source for learning tidbits like these?

Comment: @Avery, There's a [Final Fantasy Wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_Wiki) that has a lot of useful info, and there's always [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/), although you could always just ask and we'll do the heavy lifting for you, it's no trouble :)  I've played them all, with the exception of FF13-2.

Comment: I could have sworn they fixed the skillup exploit for the GBA release.